# Center numbers inside scrollbar vertically

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have this program where u can input a number and it will count from 0 until the number you've specified, I managed to get it align horizontally from 0 to 12 then it starts on a new line.

However what I want is that it orders 0 - 9 vertically then it starts a new line next to the 0 and counts from 10 until 19 and it keeps on going till it reached the specified value.

```js
 function action() {
   document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = "";
   var hoogste = document.getElementById("getallen").value;
   var count = 0;
   for (var i = 0; i < hoogste; i++) {
     document.getElementById("container").innerHTML += i + " ";
   }
 }
```

```css
#container {
  overflow: scroll;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="getallen">
<br>
<input type="button" onclick="action()" value="Submit">
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: have a look at css columns

Comment: @NewToJS tried doing <br> instead of the space but then it doesnt order from 0 - 9, but instead orders everything on the first line.

Comment: you want to break line at 9, 19, 29 etc?

Comment: have you tried by simply just changing the container size to say 180px;

Comment: have you tried using a html brake on mod 9?

Comment: @Pete Thank, you columns fixed it :)

Comment: @StanVanHoorn not sure what the current browser support for it is though - I think it shoud work in the latest browsers but not sure if ie supports it

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're looking for... Your question isn't too clear to me so I hope this is the right thing for you.

```js
function action() {
var hoogste = document.getElementById("getallen").value;
var output="";
 for (var i = 0; i<hoogste; i++) {
  if(i>0&&(i % 10)==0){
// i is more than 0 and every 10(TH)
   output+="<br/>"+i+" ";
  }else{
     output+=i+" ";
  }
 }
document.getElementById("container").innerHTML=output;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="getallen"><br>
<input type="button" onclick="action()" value="Submit">
<div id="container"></div>
```

If you have any questions about the source code above please leave a comment below and I will get back to you as soon as possible.

I hope this helps. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with `writing-mode` and `text-orientation` in CSS:

```js
function action() {
    var container = document.getElementById('container');
    var hoogste = document.getElementById("getallen").value;
    container.innerHTML = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < hoogste; i++) {

        if (i < 10) {
            var nextSpan = '<span>' + i + '</span>';
        }

        else {
            var nextSpan = '<span class="double-digit">' + i + '</span>';
        }

        container.innerHTML += nextSpan;
    }
}
```

```css
body {
font-size: 24px;
}

input {
width: 100px;
}

#container {
margin-top: 1em;
height: 14em;
width: 14em;
font-size: 1em;
writing-mode: vertical-lr;
text-orientation: upright;
vertical-align: top;
}

#container span {
display: inline-block;
width: 1em;
height: 1em;
padding: 0.2em;
}

.double-digit {
position: relative;
top: -0.15em;
writing-mode: horizontal-tb;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="getallen">
<br>
<input type="button" onclick="action()" value="Submit">
<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I added a `<br>`in the loop instead of a space, and in the #container id I added `columns: 10px;` and it works! :)

Special thanks to @Pete

Comment: Hey, you should really consider Alex's answer. `:(`

Comment: So were you looking for a CSS solution or a javascript solution?